# How many component has graph with 20 vertex at least 10 degree

Tags: graph-theory

How many maximum component can have a graph with 20 vertices and minimum 10 degrees?

My proceeding:

For first component I need one vertex with 10 degree and next 10 vertex. In sum 11 vertex.

For second component I need one vertex with 10 degree and next 10 vertex again. But it is generally 22 vertex. (11 from first and 11 from second).

So graph can has maximally one component ?

Comment: Yes, your solution is correct

Comment: Ok, thank you.       .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **Erfan Khaniki** said in the comments, your solution is correct. You can also express the same basic idea in a slightly different way:

> If the graph has more than one component, it must have at least one component $C$ with $\le 10$ vertices. But then $\deg v\le 9$ for each vertex $v$ of $C$, which is impossible. Thus, the graph can have only one component.